# Jquery ajax parametric callback and variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm not so much pro in javascript variable scopes and got stuck with one question.

If i have function which dose ajax call and then call my callback

```
function doAjaxFunc(param, callback) 
{
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/some/url/'+param,
    success: function(data){        
        callback(data);
    },
    dataType:'json'
  });
}

function someCallback1(ajaxResp){
   // DO someting 1
}

function someCallback2(ajaxResp){
   // DO someting 2
}

// exec
doAjaxFunc(1, someCallback1);
doAjaxFunc(2, someCallback2);
```

As ajax is async and it can be that sever will process param=1 case longer then param=2 is it possible that someCallback1 and someCallback2 will process not their responses. I mean callback argument value will be somehow mixed ?

If possible give some explanation details in answer

Comment: It depends how you define "mixed". Each will get called for correct param but execution order is not guaranteed as the requests can complete in any order

Comment: @charlietfl under mix i mend value mixing, order is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean callback argument value will be somehow mixed?

No. The callbacks will be called in completely separate invocations within scope of the originating AJAX `success` handler. There will be no cross-contamination of the data from either request.

Also, just as an aside, you can change this:

```
success: function(data){        
    callback(data);
},
```

To just this:

```
success: callback,
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. So you mean that inside each ajax success function will be available only its parent doAjaxFunc function passed params right ? evan if i pass 10 diferent params to doAjaxFunc(param1,param2 ...)

Comment: Is there some name for this ? so that i will google and read more to understand reason

Comment: The general term is 'scope'. It's to do with the context within variables and parameters are accessible. You seem to already know this from your question title, though :)

Comment: ok thanks, accepting your answer as you posted first in answers list

Answer (score 0):

Check this example , i hope it is some helpful to understand scope in JavaScript

```js
var isFirstCall=false;
function doAjax(param)
{
  if(!isFirstCall)
  {
    //for example after do ajax
    var millisecondsToWait = 1000;
    setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(param);  
    }, millisecondsToWait);
  }
  isFirstCall=true;
  console.log(param);  
}

doAjax('first call');
doAjax('second call');
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I understand what happening here but i would like to understand reason. So and setTimeoput and jquery ajax somehow run in exact variable scope environment and once their callback triggered only correct variable scopes are available ? how its called ?